# Wordpress/Woocommerce - Unwanted brackets in a product name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

my website is hebrew
I have woocomerce shop
there is categories names that contains hebrew and english
the english words get brackets
how can I remove it?

thanks a lot

Comment: Your product title contains both English and Hebrew? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: sorry its really a category title,  and yes it contains both English and Hebrew

Comment: someone please?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about that product name (no-title) are coming? If yes, i think you did not enter Product Title.

Comment: I am talking about a category name that contains hebrew and english,
the english words get brackets, here is a url to it: http://www.extraled.co.il/product-category/industrial-lighting/

Comment: How are you outputting the text ?